# How to get the value from a listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event from another class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a main form with a `listbox`, I also have a `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event and more code going on for each item when it changes.

Is there a simple way to make this event in another class and not on the main form?

If not, as I meant, I don't want all this code on my main form's code so I want to move it to another class where it is more related.

what is the "best practice" way to notify `Class B` when `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` occurs? is it by a delegate? I tried to figure it out but didn't really understand. Help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use partial to split your class files. And learn delegate surely, it's needed and very useful. Simple way, pass listBox1 to that 'another class' and add event inside that class

Comment: you could use MVP approach (Model-View-Presenter). It`s common practice to handle events from Form (View) in Presenter (another class) via interface.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how both classes are linked to each other and their types but using following code you can get idea to solve your problem

```
public class A
{
   public delegate void ItemSelectedHandler(string title);
   public event ItemSelectedHandler OnItemSelected;
   public void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArg, e)
   {
       //other code
       if(OnItemSelected!=null)
       {
          OnItemSelected("Something");
       }
   }
   public void LaunchB()
   {
      var b = new B(this);
      b.ShowDialog();
   }
}

public class B
{
   private A _parent;
   public B(A parent)
   {
      _parent = parent;
      _parent.OnItemSelected += onItemSelected;
   }
   public void onItemSelected(string title)
   { 
      //will fire when selected index changed;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @M. Nasser Javaid, so basically, you create a delegate and an event in `Class A`, and then you pass `Class A` object in the constructor of `class B` so you can get it's fields in class B right? and then you create an event in `class B` that whenever the event in `class A` is fired it causes the event in `class B` to be fired as well right?.. Nice.. Thank you for the answer, but 1) isn't there a way to do it without passing `Class A` object? 2) when you do pass an object of `class A`, is it the object itself or just a reference to that object? Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, my main class is a windows form and `Class B` is just a class in another file (.cs file). I create an instance of `Class B` in the main form in any case.

Comment: So replace `ShowDialog()` with other simple method which you are calling from `A`

Comment: Please take a look at my answer as well, Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved my question in a simpler way.

1. I set the `listbox1` access modifier to `Internal`
2. I created properties for the main form.
3. In `Class B`, I subscribed to the listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged event and created an event handler like this:

`form1Properties.listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged+=listBox1_SelectedIndexChangedforClassB;`

4. Then I've implemented the event handler in `Class B` like this:

`private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChangedforClassB(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("listbox1 selected item has changed!");
    }`

I hope I am using all the right terms, please correct me if I'm wrong, and please tell me if you find my solution is flawed in any way. Thanks.