# How to call event from class?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my form:

```
namespace Secretary_1._0
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
     }

}
```

This is my class:

```
namespace Secretary_1._0
{

    public partial class Client
    {
        public static Form1 formCall = new Form1();


        public static void Clients_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {     
            formCall.clientPanel.Visible = true;
            formCall.clientLabel.Visible = true;
            formCall.addClientButton.Visible = true;
            formCall.clientListPanel.Visible = true;
            formCall.clientListPanel.BringToFront();
            formCall.addClientLabel.Visible = false;
            formCall.clientInfoPanel.Visible = false;
        }

        public static void addClientButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            formCall.clientPanel.Visible = true;
            formCall.addClientLabel.Visible = true;
            formCall.clientInfoPanel.Visible = true;
            formCall.clientInfoPanel.BringToFront();
            formCall.addClientButton.Visible = false;
            formCall.clientListPanel.Visible = false;
            formCall.clientAddPropertyPanel.Visible = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Edited:

My question is how do I call the Button_Click Event from the Client Class?

When the Client button is clicked in Form1 I want to call the events located in the Client Class.

Is this possible? Am I missing something? Ive searched every where but I seem not to understand.

I plan to create a lot of buttons and would like to create a class for certain buttons so that my form1.cs isnt so long.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this

```
//Set Access Modifier of that button to public or internal for same namespace
namespace Secretary_1._0
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void StartClient()
        {
            var client = new Client(this);
            client.RequiredMethod();  //Call here method of client
        }
    }
}
```

Now

```
namespace Secretary_1._0
{

    public partial class Client
    {
         public Form1 formCall;

         //Constructor
         public Client(Form1 form1)
         {
              formCall = form1;
              formCall.someButton.Click += OnSomeButtonClick;
         }

         public void OnSomeButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             //Code here to on form1 button click ...
         }

         public static void Clients_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {     
             formCall.clientPanel.Visible = true;
             formCall.clientLabel.Visible = true;
             formCall.addClientButton.Visible = true;
             formCall.clientListPanel.Visible = true;
             formCall.clientListPanel.BringToFront();
             formCall.addClientLabel.Visible = false;
             formCall.clientInfoPanel.Visible = false;
         }

         public static void addClientButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

             formCall.clientPanel.Visible = true;
             formCall.addClientLabel.Visible = true;
             formCall.clientInfoPanel.Visible = true;
             formCall.clientInfoPanel.BringToFront();
             formCall.addClientButton.Visible = false;
             formCall.clientListPanel.Visible = false;
             formCall.clientAddPropertyPanel.Visible = false;
         }

     }
}
```

Edit: Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469203/how-to-get-the-value-from-a-listbox1-selectedindexchanged-event-from-another-cla/31469362#31469362) post to resolve issue using event.

Answer (score 0):

1-open Form1.Designer.Cs

2-search about your button generated code

3-the last line in button code must be like that
`this.btn_insert.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);`

Note : button1 = your button name

4-Replace The last line i just mentioned above and add this one instead 
`this.btn_insert.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Clients_Click);`

Hope This will Help You :)

i have to mention this process mean passing a method to the delegate(EventHandler) Which necessary to the event to work correctly.

Comment: Sorry i get a error when i tried that. I forgot to mention i already edited the Form1.Desighner.cs with (this.Clients.Click += new System.EventHandler(Client.Clients_Click);) without the parenthesis and i get no error but when the button is pressed nothing happens.

Comment: Can you add code for passing a method to the delegate(EventHandler)

Comment: You must to attach the click Event from the properties box to your method (Clients_Click) >> simply by choosing it from the combo box

Comment: This Code mean that i passed the method which called button1_click to the delegate which called Event Handler 

>>" this.btn_insert.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click) ";

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Visual Studio.  Go into the solution explorer.  Click to expand Form1.cs.  Find the Form1 class in the tree and expand it.  Click into one of your components there to cause VS to open the code for your Form1.designer.cs.  At the bottom of that page should be a list of your components.  All of them are private.  Change the ones you need from private to internal, and you will have access to them from other classes in your program.  Be warned, though, I think you might get some undocumented behavior doing this.  But it will let you get at those forms objects from another class in the program.

Comment: Note this only lets you access those controls in another class besides Form1.  You will still need to follow Mohamed Elhabbab's advice to handle events there.